# iphone DatePickerView - PickerView - modal View or Popup? what is best?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, datepicker, uipickerview

I need Picker Views and Date Picker Views all over my app.  Should I make a class for date and another for pickers and have a new window come up.... or should I try and popup the views on top of what I have already displayed?

Also do I need a button to say DONE or something to trigger to go back to the previous screen?

What is best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`UIActionSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with `UIPickerView`/`UIDatePickerView` is the best way to do it.